# select for timeout over TCP socket

Tags: sockets, select, timeout, connect

I have a problem with this code:

```
FD_ZERO(&cset);
FD_SET(s, &cset);

tval.tv_sec = TIMEOUT; 
tval.tv_usec = 0; 

n = select(FD_SETSIZE, &cset, NULL, NULL, &tval);

if (n==-1) {
    printf(" select() failed \n");
    exit(-1);
}
if (n>0) {
    check_control = connect(s,(struct sockaddr*)
    &indirizzo_remoto,sizeof(indirizzo_remoto));

    if (check_control == -1) {
        printf("Errore connect()\n");
    }

}else{
    printf("Timeout. I'll shutdown the client");
    exit(-1);
}
```

I want insert a timeout for the connect but it doesn't work:

I use the right IP address and port number of the Server but the connection goes to timeout.

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Yes, with telnet it works!

Comment: Is this wrong? Because I want that is the Server is down when the client try to connect with it if it takes 30 seconds the client stop and close the socket

Comment: (sorry for the English) ....: I want that if the Server / when the client try to connect to it

Comment: select() is not going to connect() the socket for you. If you want to connect() with a timeout you need to 1. Set the socket to non-blocking mode. 2. call connect() 3. call select(). Have you done step 1 and step 2 ? We only see the code for step 3.

Comment: I thought that only this piece of code realized the desired result. How can I accomplish steps 1 and 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `select()` to check if a given socket is in a **readable** state before calling `connect()` on that same socket.  That will never work.  An unconnected TCP socket will never be in a readable state, and cannot be used with `select()` until `connect()` has been called on it first.

The only way to implement a timeout for a `connect()` call is to put the socket into non-blocking mode first (sockets are blocking by default), then call `connect()` (which returns an `EINPROGRESS` error if the socket is attempting to connect), and then use `select()` to wait for the socket to enter a **writable** state, indicating the connection was successful, or an **error** state, indicating the connection failed.

Try this:

```
fcntl(s, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK);
```

Or:

```
flags = 1;
ioctl(s, FIOBIO, &flags);
```

Depending on your platform.

Then:

```
check_control = connect(s, (struct sockaddr*) &indirizzo_remoto, sizeof(indirizzo_remoto));
if (check_control == -1)
{
    if (errno != EINPROGRESS)
    {
        printf("Errore connect()\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    FD_ZERO(&wset);
    FD_SET(s, &wset);

    FD_ZERO(&eset);
    FD_SET(s, &eset);

    tval.tv_sec = TIMEOUT; 
    tval.tv_usec = 0; 

    n = select(s+1, NULL, &wset, &eset, &tval);
    if (n == -1)
    {
        printf(" select() failed \n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if (n == 0)
    {
        printf("Timeout. I'll shutdown the client");
        exit(-1);
    }

    if (FD_ISSET(s, &eset))
    {
        printf("Cannot connect. I'll shutdown the client");
        exit(-1);
    }

    int err = -1;
    getsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &err, sizeof(err));
    if (err != 0)
    {
        printf("Cannot connect. I'll shutdown the client");
        exit(-1);
    }
}

// connected...
```

Comment: Now it works. Thank you for pointing out the (obvious) issues!